# Hosts.deny blocks whm access?

Tags: linux, centos, hosts

I have my hosts.allow and hosts.deny set up as follows:

Allow:

```
sshd: (my static ip)
vsftpd: (my static ip)
```

Deny:

```
ALL : ALL
```

but this blocks all access to WHM and cPanel?

What else do I need to put in allow to enable these for myself?

Would the following be suitable?

```
ALL : (my static ip)
```

Comment: The tcpwrappers is a bit old-school.  Is there some reason why you aren't setting up a iptables-based firewall?  Or have you done that as well?

Comment: @Zoredache I'm the only user with a static ip that needs access to the server so I just thought this was the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Adding your IP to hosts.allow should be fine. But. But as Zoredache mentioned tcpwrappers library is inserted voluntary "between the service and internet" see [Wikipedia TCP Wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper). It means that it is optional and not all services support it. Some will just ignore the configuration. For example services written by you. You should at least test each one used on your server.
Firewall would be probably more trustworthy.

Answer (score -1):

You Should try below in host.allow.

SSHD :  IP : ALLOW

WHOSTMGRD : IP : ALLOW

Cpaneld : IP : ALLOW (Not really necessary if you have added above two)